# Normal subgroup question, left and right cosets.

Tags: normal-subgroups

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. If for each $a \in G$ there exists $b \in G$ such that $aH = Hb$, show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Im tutoring a person in first year abstract algebra, Im having a trouble getting this to work, I know theres some little detail or catch im missing. I can get to the point where all we need to show is $ba^{-1} \in H$ to prove  $aHa^{-1} = H$ (abusive notation).

Answer (score 0):

For right cosets we have

> $Hx=Hy \iff x\in Hy \iff xy^{-1}\in H \iff yx^{-1}\in H \iff y\in Hx$.

From the given assumption, if $aH=Hb$, then we have $a\in aH=Hb$, so that, by the above, $Hb=Ha$, and that means

> $aH=Ha\ \iff\ aHa^{-1}=H$.